# Search for a recent added keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

Say if there is a Table that has 100 Million Records.. More and more data keeps getting updated now and then. Your mission is to search for a recently added keyword say "srinu" from that table each and every 30 seconds and to display it.

What is the efficient way to do this ?

No need to write any code. Just give your views/thoughts on this.

Comment: If I need to perform a query - I'm performing a query.

Comment: this sounds less of database and for of data structures question....`Heap`...... interview right!!???

Comment: How often is the table updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather abstract question and will have a lot of opinionated answers.

What is the criteria for "recently added"?

If I needed a quick query to see what records were added within the last 30 seconds
I would create a trigger and a secondary lookup table
after update and after insert insert into recently_added;

and create an event to delete from recently_added where the datetime field is less than than 30 seconds ago and run it every 30 seconds
This step can be moved to the trigger and a criteria added to the select instead

This way I would SELECT * FROM recently_added if there were no records found I know that no records were updated within the last 30 seconds. Otherwise all of the keywords updated within the last 30 seconds are listed

Answer (score 0):

Use Elasticsearch. First index data into database using any river like MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch. So that if any new data is added to database it automatically syncs with elasticsearch and from there you can search the recent doc added.